# Why is Enumerable omitted while calling this method? Namespace confusion

Tags: c#

I saw a solution to one coding problem which had this line of code

```
using System;    
using System.Linq;    

return string.Concat(dna.Select(GetComplement));
```

I couldn't figure out what Select does and I tried to search it on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/, but I couldn't find it. Later, I found something that seems to be it under System.Linq.Enumerable.Select. Is that it? If so, why is Enumerable omitted while calling this method? Why not:

```
return string.Concat(dna.Enumerable.Select(GetCmpolement));
```

Comment: It is an extension method. `dna.Select(GetCmpolement)` = `Enumerable.Select(dna, GetCmploement)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Enumerable.Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8) is an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods). Look closely at the method signatures in the documentation at that first link and you'll see that the first parameter (the `IEnumerable`) has a `this` in front of it, meaning you can call it on an `IEnumerable` as if it were actually defined on `IEnumerable`.